# Binomial Heap Insertion java

Tags: java

I'm having trouble inserting into a binomial heap, When I call insert 1 it prints (1) and then I insert 2 it displays (2) instead of (1(2)) and then three it displays (3) instead of (3)(1(2)). I would be very grateful if someone could help figure out my problem. Thank you in advance. Here is my code

```
public class BHeap {

    int key;
    int degree;//The degree(Number of children)
    BHeap parent, leftmostChild, rightmostChild, rightSibling,root,previous,next;
    public BHeap(){
        key =0;
        degree=0;
        parent =null;
        leftmostChild=null;
        rightmostChild=null;
        rightSibling=null;
        root=null;
        previous=null;
        next=null;
    }
    public BHeap merge(BHeap y){
        BHeap newHeap = new BHeap();
        BHeap currentHeap = y;
        BHeap nextHeap = y.rightSibling;
        while(currentHeap.rightSibling !=null){
            if(currentHeap.degree==nextHeap.degree){
                if(currentHeap.key<nextHeap.key){
                    if(currentHeap.degree ==0){
                        currentHeap.leftmostChild=nextHeap;
                        currentHeap.rightmostChild=nextHeap;
                        currentHeap.rightSibling=nextHeap.rightSibling;
                        nextHeap.rightSibling=null;
                        nextHeap.parent=currentHeap;
                        currentHeap.degree++;
                    }
                    else{
                        newHeap = currentHeap;
                        newHeap.rightmostChild.rightSibling=nextHeap;
                        newHeap.rightmostChild=nextHeap;
                        nextHeap.parent=newHeap;
                        newHeap.degree++;
                        nextHeap.rightSibling=null;
                        nextHeap=newHeap.rightSibling;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if(currentHeap.degree==0){
                        nextHeap.rightmostChild=currentHeap;
                        nextHeap.rightmostChild.root = nextHeap.rightmostChild;//add
                        nextHeap.leftmostChild=currentHeap;
                        nextHeap.leftmostChild.root = nextHeap.leftmostChild;//add
                        currentHeap.parent=nextHeap;
                        currentHeap.rightSibling=null;
                        currentHeap.root=currentHeap;//add
                        nextHeap.degree++;
                    }
                    else{
                        newHeap=nextHeap;
                        newHeap.rightmostChild.rightSibling=currentHeap;
                        newHeap.rightmostChild=currentHeap;
                        currentHeap.parent= newHeap;
                        newHeap.degree++;
                        currentHeap=newHeap.rightSibling;
                        currentHeap.rightSibling=null;
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                currentHeap=currentHeap.rightSibling;
                nextHeap=nextHeap.rightSibling;
            }
        }
        return y;
    }
    public void Insert(int x){
        BHeap newHeap= new BHeap();
        newHeap.key=x;
        if(this.root==null){
            this.root=newHeap;
        }
        else{
            this.root = merge(newHeap);
        }
    }
    public void Display(){
        System.out.print("(");
        System.out.print(this.root.key);
        if(this.leftmostChild != null){
            this.leftmostChild.Display();
        }
        System.out.print(")");
        if(this.rightSibling!=null){
            this.rightSibling.Display();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it by any chance?

Comment: @Cruncher Yes I did debug and everything is pointing to where it is suppose to be pointing and setting everything correctly

Comment: @Rod Your question has no permanent value without the code. If you don't want to show it, delete the entire question.

Comment: @EJP I'm confused, my code is right there... I didn't delete my code, I'm looking right at it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are inserting, you are making a new `BHeap` object and then passing that to `merge()`. Your new `BHeap` has no `rightSibling`, so you skip the entire `while` loop and just return the new `BHeap`. So the new `BHeap` becomes the `root` of the whole `BHeap` and you throw out what was there before.

**Update:** I'm not going to write pseudo-code because it's right there in *your* code.

So you make a new `BHeap` and `Insert(1)`. Your `Insert` method makes a second new `BHeap` and then checks the `root` of the current `BHeap`. That's null, so the second `BHeap` becomes the `root`. That's fine.

Now you `Insert(2)`. Again, create another `BHeap`. This time the `root` of the current `BHeap` is not null so we call `merge` passing in the new `BHeap`. Note that this new `BHeap` is now referred (inside `merge`) as `y`. Also note that you have done nothing to this new `BHeap` aside from setting the `key` field so *all other fields are null*.

Inside `merge` you make yet another `BHeap` object, and make another reference `currentHeap` that refers to `y`. (Again, only the `key` field has been set so all other fields are null.) You refer to y's `rightSibling` as `nextHeap` and then comes the `while` loop. The `while` loop says that while the `rightSibling` of `currentHeap` is not null, do a bunch of stuff.

But as I've said above, *everything* about `currentHeap` (aka `y` aka the brand new `BHeap` you created in `Insert`) is ***null***. So the entire `while` loop is skipped and you return `y` from `merge`.

`Insert` then accepts the return value from `y` and sets that as the `root` of the current `BHeap`. The old `root` is discarded and sits in the corner weeping bitterly at its sad fate before the garbage collector comes along and shuffles it into an early grave. The new `root` cheers triumphantly and reigns supreme, the king of the `BHeap` (and the only member of the `BHeap`)... until you call `Insert(3)`.

And you? You learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Could you possibly write Psuedo code of your answer to help me understand what you're saying clearer?

Answer (score 1):

In your method `merge` you pass a `BHeap` object `y`.  You do change anything as the `BHeap` object you have created and passed to `merge` in your `insert` method does not add any siblings.  The while loop is never run.

Also, I think you may want to review your `merge` method.  It seems you do not ever take into account the current `BHeap` that you are merging into and simply reformat the given `BHeap` argument.